# MySQL: stopping just one DB to allow it to be moved

Tags: mysql, backup

I want to do some work on the files that make up a few MySQL DBs (moving the files to a different partition and symlinking the original location to this) and if possible I'd like to shutdown just the database being moved, rather than shutting MySQL down altogether.

Is there anyway in MySQL to do this, or will I need to do a full MySQL shutdown to be able to move the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can lock a database to prevent access you can't "stop" it. It's the service itself that is started and stopped, which of course affects all databases it handles. If the issue is disk space I suggest moving the whole lot, rather than just one database.

Comment: Thanks, it's an 8GB DB and a bunch of sub 10MB DBs so I don't want to take out all prod sites for just one, but I'll manage a way to schedule this.